# Issues using openmp to parallelize Gauss Seidel in C

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm working on a project which aims to improve the computation time of conducting Gauss-Seidel problem.

I've figured out how to create an even-odd checkerboard of the data points which in theory should eliminate the data dependency.

What I'm aiming to do is to have one thread working on the even points and then another thread work on the odd points. See the serial code below.

My current attempt of openmp have not been successful

Serial Version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>    // Using omp_get_wtime
#include <math.h>   // Using sqrt`

//This first function is for the starting y point on the even odd checkerboard
int t;
int start_point_odd(int value)
{ 
 if (value%2 == 0)
    {
      t = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      t = 2;
    }

 return t;
}

int start_point_even(int value)
{ 
 if (value%2 == 0)
    {
      t = 2;
    }
    else
    {
      t = 1;
    }

 return t;
}

//   ============================================================
double sqr(double x) { return x*x; } 
int s;
double gauss_seidel(int n, double phi[n+1][n+1])
{ 
  double phi_xy_old,diff=0;
  int x,y,p;



#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
#pragma omp sections 
{
  #pragma omp section 
  {
  for (x=1;x<n;x++) 
    for (y=start_point_odd(x);y<n;y+=2) 
    {  
      phi_xy_old = phi[x][y]; 
      phi[x][y] = 0.25 * (
        phi[x+1][y  ] + phi[x-1][y  ]
      + phi[x  ][y+1] + phi[x  ][y-1]);
      diff += sqr(phi_xy_old - phi[x][y]); 
    }
  diff=sqrt(diff / (double) ((n-1)*(n-1)) ); 
  return diff; 
  }
  
  #pragma omp section 
  {
  for (x=1;x<n;x++) 
    for (y=start_point_even(x);y<n;y+=2)   
    {
      phi_xy_old = phi[x][y]; 
      phi[x][y] = 0.25 * (
        phi[x+1][y  ] + phi[x-1][y  ]
      + phi[x  ][y+1] + phi[x  ][y-1]);
      diff += sqr(phi_xy_old - phi[x][y]); 
    }

  diff=sqrt(diff / (double) ((n-1)*(n-1)) );
   
 }
}
}
return diff;
}
```

My attempt at using openmp

```
int t;
int start_point_odd(int value)
{ 
 if (value%2 == 0)
    {
      t = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      t = 2;
    }

 return t;
}

int start_point_even(int value)
{ 
 if (value%2 == 0)
    {
      t = 2;
    }
    else
    {
      t = 1;
    }

 return t;
}

//   ============================================================
double sqr(double x) { return x*x; } 
int s;
double gauss_seidel(int n, double phi[n+1][n+1])
{ 
  double phi_xy_old,diff=0;
  int x,y,p;



#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
#pragma omp sections 
{
  #pragma omp section 
  {
  for (x=1;x<n;x++) 
    for (y=start_point_odd(x);y<n;y+=2) 
    {  
      phi_xy_old = phi[x][y]; 
      phi[x][y] = 0.25 * (
        phi[x+1][y  ] + phi[x-1][y  ]
      + phi[x  ][y+1] + phi[x  ][y-1]);
      diff += sqr(phi_xy_old - phi[x][y]); 
    }
  diff=sqrt(diff / (double) ((n-1)*(n-1)) ); 
  return diff; 
  }
  
  #pragma omp section 
  {
  for (x=1;x<n;x++) 
    for (y=start_point_even(x);y<n;y+=2)   
    {
      phi_xy_old = phi[x][y]; 
      phi[x][y] = 0.25 * (
        phi[x+1][y  ] + phi[x-1][y  ]
      + phi[x  ][y+1] + phi[x  ][y-1]);
      diff += sqr(phi_xy_old - phi[x][y]); 
    }

  diff=sqrt(diff / (double) ((n-1)*(n-1)) );
   
 }
}
}
return diff;
}
```

I want to implement openmp to run one thread on the even points and one thread on the odd points

Comment: You have race conditions in your code. Define your variables in the minimum required scope and use `default(none)` clause. It forces you to set the sharing attribute of all your variables. Note that you cannot use `return` inside a parallel block. Your serial code contains openmp pragmas, can you show us your serial code?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to Red/Black is flawed. You can do the red points in parallel with a parallel loop, and likewise the black, but the one set really needs to come after the other.

If you work on both at the same time you have a "chaotic" iterative method. There is theory about that, but no one uses them, probably for a reason.

Comment: Note that Victor Eijkhout's approach also allows much more parallelism, since it operates in parallel on half of the array at a time, whereas your approach only has two way parallelism, so cannot exploit more than two hardware threads...